# Automatically open latest powerpoint file in folder

Tags: windows, batch-file, powerpoint

I've been looking for a script to automatically open the latest PowerPoint show in a folder. I have a couple computers that are used for presenting information to staff and would like to have it open the latest version of the PowerPoint Show without me having to do it. I've see something like it mentioned before but never could find the script myself.

Comment: So you can use a `FOR /F` command to read the output of the `DIR` command.  You will want to use specific `DIR` options so I would start by reading the help files for both of these commands.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your file extensions are "pptx" and they are all contained in the same folder you could use the following batch file to start the file that was most recently modified:

```
for /F "delims=" %%i in ('dir /B /O:-D *.txt') do (
    start "dummy" "%%i"
    exit /B 0
)
```

Comment: Why waste the cpu cycles on the CALL.  Just open the file within the FOR command and exit.

Comment: Good point. This code was borrowed from something else and I didn't really edit it. Fixed answer